# How to drop duplicate with priority in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new you to pandas and python, and I want to remove duplicates but give it a priority. It's hard to explain but I will give an example to make it clear

```
ID      Phone   Email
0001    0234+    null
0001    null    a@.com
0001    0234+    a@.com
```

how I can remove the duplicates in ID and leave the third one because it has both phone and email
and not removing it randomly, and if the id for example has no complete of both values it will still remain one

Comment: Would you still want to drop the rows with null if there is no row with complete information of both fields ?

Comment: I need to leave one at least so no

Comment: So you need solution other than those already posted which remove null rows without checking any row of full set data available beforehand.

Comment: Yes if possible, it's my bad didn't explain it well, I update the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this by take each case to new data frame for example if both email and phone have value will set it a firstdf, then if email only has value it will be in seconddf, etc.

then I concat them and append it to new data frame as final result
and remove id duplicate (by that I set the most important case at top)

code:

```
# drop if both is null
ff = ff.dropna(subset=["الجوال", 'البريد الالكتروني'] , how="all")

#hh = ff with both not null
hh = ff.dropna(subset=["الجوال", 'البريد الالكتروني'])

## ss = ff with email false and phone true
ss = ff.dropna(subset=["الجوال"])

## yy = ff with email true and phone false
yy = ff.dropna(subset=["البريد الالكتروني"])

#### solution to give priority which to drop we take the most important one top
df1=pd.concat([hh,ss],axis=0)
len(hh) + len(ss)

df2=pd.concat([df1,yy],axis=0)
len(df1) + len(yy)

final= df2.copy()

final= final.drop_duplicates(subset=["رقم الهوية"])

final.to_excel(r'Result.xlsx',index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

First Drop NaNs in rows and then drop duplicates

```
df2 = df.dropna(subset=['Phone']).dropna(subset=['Email']).drop_duplicates('ID')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just drop the `NaN` values based on `Phone` and `Email`.

```
df.dropna(subset=['Phone', 'Email'], inplace=True)
```